# Question deleted by original poster even though it has an answer from another user

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

I answered [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429057/replacing-a-max-pooling-layer-with-an-average-pooling-layer-on-a-vgg-model/65429290#65429290) which later got deleted by the original poster. I thought threads couldn't get deleted if there had been at least one answer. Is that still true? If so, what happened to this thread?

The page is still accessible to me, but not when logged-off.

[image]

Comment: it has to be upvoted for deletion to be prevented

Comment: Ah, I see. That's a bit unfortunate since it seemed to have helped the OP...

Comment: You could post the question yourself and then self-answer.

Comment: You could also vote to undelete the question.  Unless it was caused by a typo

Comment: I've undeleted the Q&A now.

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated. @SecurityHound I couldn't, since it was deleted by OP (not closed).

Comment: @Ivan - I routinely vote to undelete questions that are deleted by the author.  However, you can’t view deleted questions, so that might be the reason you cannot do that