# Same user repeatedly deletes questions which have valid answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I have already posted about this issue [***Question deleted by original poster even though it has an answer from another user***](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403965/question-deleted-by-original-poster-even-though-it-has-an-answer-from-another-us), but the post was about *why it happened*. As such it was tagged as duplicate, rightly so.

This has happened to me on other occasions, users asking a question, getting an answer then deleting. However, this particular individual has a strange habit of deleting questions even after having exchanged with the answerer (me) in the comment section. I thought a flag would not be enough to combine all these facts. So I decided to turn to meta Stack Overflow.

Here is the timeline:

- (2020-12-23) first encounter  I can remember of: [***Replacing a max pooling layer with an average pooling layer on a VGG model***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65429057/replacing-a-max-pooling-layer-with-an-average-pooling-layer-on-a-vgg-model/65429290#65429290). The question was deleted by OP then undeleted by a moderator (see meta post above).
- (2020-12-28) second encounter: user asks [***PyTorch tensor dimension multiplication***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480530/pytorch-tensor-dimension-multiplication/65480872#65480872). (1) I provide an answer; (2) User comments; (3) I respond; (4) question gets deleted by OP for no apparent reason.
- (2020-12-28) same day, user posts a duplicate of the previous question. I can't find this post because it has been deleted since then... I kindly ask OP in the comments to edit her/his/their previous post (where I had already provided an answer), instead of duplicating the post (at this point the original question had been deleted by OP...). She/He/They told me reason why the question was deleted is because the answer wasn't what user was looking for (or something along those lines). So OP complied: deleted the duplicate and undeleted the previous one. So we were back on [***PyTorch tensor...***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65480530/pytorch-tensor-dimension-multiplication/65480872#65480872).

  I respectfully wrote in the comments:

  > Thank you for undeleting this post (you can delete the new one now..). Welcome to Stack Overflow ____. If you feel an answer doesn't fit your question, you shouldn't just delete the whole thing to create an exact same replica. It's quite rude for those who have spent time answering! Please edit your question if the answer below isn't right for you.

  Then we have a short discussion by the end of which OP realized the answer I gave was correct:

  > I'm starting to think I got it wrong and you got it right, [...] This one seems to work!! Thanks a lot! ([*source*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65480530/6331369))

  So in the end the **OP was satisfied with the answer, *yet* it was deleted once again**.
- (2020-12-20) later that day, I didn't even realize it was the same user asking. I give an answer to [***Calculate alpha values with torch mean?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65471913/calculate-alpha-values-with-torch-mean/65472005#65472005). I don't get any comments from it, instead the answer is deleted by OP.

On these three occasions, on three different posts with user as OP, I gave an answer which seemed to fill OP's needs.

---

Some people will probably recommend I never answer this user's questions ever again, but does that solve the problem? No.

User has a total of four questions (non-deleted questions I should say). All answers to these questions have zero upvote, none has been accepted. I am quite sure many other questions have been deleted along with their answers. Even after having explained the user not to delete questions, the problem remains.

This is not about self-censoring as somebody pointed out, since one of these answers was explicitly considered valid by the OP but not marked as such.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can self-censoring end up with a question ban?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311810/can-self-censoring-end-up-with-a-question-ban) "deleting a question right after someone posts an answer to it... is seen as so overtly hostile that it does impose a pretty stiff penalty..."

Comment: I don't see how this relates to this issue. The three questions asked by OP don't have trivial answers, and OP deleted them not because of self-censoring (since a duplicate was posted later on) but because OP believed the answer I gave wasn't right. Maybe last sentence wasn't so clear, or my question is ill-posed.

Comment: The questions are undeleted and I've reached out to the user. I think we can consider this sorted for now.

Comment: what you describe is just a self censoring, asker decided that neither the question nor the answer are worth keeping and attempted to delete. I guess if it wasn't undeleted they would already hit a question ban (probably ban mechanics need to be adjusted to count answered questions undeleted by a moderator against the asker)

Comment: "what you describe is just a self censoring, asker decided that neither the question nor the answer are worth keeping and attempted to delete". Does this still hold if OP deletes the post (which has an answer) only to open up a duplicate one? Which seems identical to force deleting the answers to his/her question.

Comment: Who cares about that, sometimes this happens even when the user hasn't git an downvote. one answer more r minus who cares

Comment: @nbk it's the act of vandalisation that is being moderated here, not just the deletion of one piece of content.

Comment: the post author has the right to delete gis question, as dio people who answer, even when it is not downvoted. Moderators shouldn't undelete a question, when the author doesn't want the question to show up anymore

Comment: "*does that solve the problem? No.*" Actually it does solve your problem...